# Rails: = provide(:title, t('.title')) fails if there is a single quote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, slim-lang

I can't figure out how to fix a problem with a title translation that contains a single quote. More of that it happens only when calling

```
= provide(:title, t('.title'))
```

When referencing the same YAML translation as H2, it is displayed correctly:

```
.row
  h2 = t('.title')
```

Here is a line of YAML translation line:

```
home:
    faq:
      title: FAQ
    about:
      title: "À propos d\'Entreprise"
```

The title is displayed as follows

```
À propos d&#39;Entreprise
```

Any idea about how to solve that ? Thank you.
**OS: OS X
Rails 4.2.5
Ruby 2.3.0
YAML**

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to fix that. I think it is due to the [way](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Output_without_HTML_escaping___) that Slim interprets code snippets

So here is what I had in application.tml.slim:

```
title =full_title(yield(:title))
```

The working version is:

```
title ==full_title(yield(:title))
```

Hope this helps.